# Proving that if $A_n\xrightarrow{s}A$, $\sup\limits_{n\in\mathbb N}\|A_n\|<\infty$, $B_n\xrightarrow{s}B$, then $A_nB_n\xrightarrow{s}AB$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

> Prove that if $A_n\xrightarrow{s}A$, $\sup\limits_{n\in\mathbb N}\|A_n\|<\infty$, $B_n\xrightarrow{s}B$, then $A_nB_n\xrightarrow{s}AB$.

$\xrightarrow{s}$ is the convergence wrt strong topology, $\xrightarrow{w}$ is convergence wrt weak topology. $\mathcal B(X,Y)$ is the set of all bounded function from $X$ to $Y$.

Let $X, Y, Z$ be normed spaces and $A_n, A \in \mathcal B(Y,Z),\ B_n,B \in \mathcal B(X,Y)$.

Then,

$$ \bigg(A_n \xrightarrow{s} A,\ \sup_{n \in \mathbb N} \|A_n\|<\infty,\ B_n \xrightarrow{s} B\bigg)\Rightarrow \bigg(A_nB_n\xrightarrow{s}AB\bigg)$$

$$ \bigg(A_n \xrightarrow{w} A,\ \sup_{n \in \mathbb N} \|A_n\|<\infty,\ B_n \xrightarrow{s} B\bigg)\Rightarrow \bigg(A_nB_n\xrightarrow{w}AB\bigg)$$

> My question is if this also holds true if we don't have the assumption that $\sup_{n \in \mathbb N} \|A_n\|<\infty$

If $X$, $Y$, $Z$ are Banach spaces it holds true (the proof uses the principle of uniform boundedness). So I guess it does not hold true if $X$, $Y$, $Z$ are simply normed spaces (and not Banach spaces) but I have no idea how to show it

--

So, by 'usual basis' you mean $e_i=(0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots,0)$ where we have $1$ for the i-th component and $0$ else?

Then we have $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}=(\lambda_1e_1,\ldots,\lambda_ie_i,\ldots,\lambda_Ne_N,0,0\ldots)$ for every $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb N} \in C_{00}(\mathbb N)$, right? (because we only have finite support), $\lambda_i \in \mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$

How does $e_n^*$ look like?

Furthermore, $A_n(e_i)=2^ne_1\otimes e_n^*(e_i)=2^n\delta_{ni}e_i=\begin{cases}2^ne_n,&i=n\\0,&i\neq n\end{cases}$

$B_n(e_i)=\frac{1}{n}e_n\otimes e_1^*(e_i)=\frac{1}{n}\delta_{1i}e_i=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{n}e_1,&i=1\\0,&i\neq 1\end{cases}$

But I don't understand how $A_n$ takes the nth component to the first component, and $B_n$ takes the first component to the nth component?

What does $A_nB_n$ do with a vector in $c_{00}(\mathbb N)$?

Basically, I don't really understand how $A_n((x_n)), B_n((x_n))$ and $A_nB_n((x_n))$ work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statements are true generally and do not need the uniform boundedness theorem. For the first statement:
$$\|(AB-A_nB_n)x\|= \| (A-A_n)B x +A_n(B-B_n)x\|≤ \|(A-A_n)Bx\|+\|A_n\|\ \|(B-B_n)x\|$$
since $\|A_n\|$ is bounded the right-hand side goes to $0$ under your hypothesis, implying $A_nB_n\to AB$ in the strong topology. This works independently of any completeness assumptions.

For the second case do exactly the same thing, for every $f\in Z^*$ you've got:
$$|f([A_nB_m-AB]x)|≤ |f([A-A_n]Bx)| + \|f\|\ \|A_n\|\ \|(B-B_n)x\|.$$

In the case the assumption on the norms is dropped the statements are no longer true (provided the spaces are not all Banach). Consider $X=Y=Z=c_{00}(\Bbb N)$ the space of finite support sequences with supremum norm. Let $e_n$ be the usual basis and $e_n^*$ the usual dual element given by "evaluation". Then $A_n = 2^n e_1\otimes e_n^*, B_n = \frac1n e_n\otimes e_1^*$ satisfy the conditions (both converge strongly to $0$) but $A_n B_n = \frac{2^n}{n} e_1\otimes e_1^*$ doesn't converge to $0$.

(The map $e_k\otimes e_j^*$ is given by linear extension of $e_k\otimes e_j^*( e_n) = \delta_{jn} e_n$.)

Comment: That's exactly how I did it, so I'm wondering: We don't even use the assumption $\sup_{n \in \mathbb N}\|A_n\|<\infty$? We reason that the limit is $0$ because $A_n$ is bounded and not because $\sup_{n \in \mathbb N}\|A_n\|<\infty$?

Comment: $\sup_{n\in\Bbb N} \|A_n\|<\infty$ is exactly the same statement as $\|A_n\|$ being bounded. In the case of Banach spaces uniform boundedness gives you that strong convergence of $A_n$ makes  the sequence $\|A_n\|$ bounded, making this assumption superfluous (but this does not generalise to nets I think).

Comment: Yes and what I am asked to do is to show if the above implications still hold true if $\sup_{n \in \mathbb N}\|A_n\|=\infty$

Comment: Ah I see, it appears I didn't see the big highlighted box remarking on this. In these cases it is not true, I'll add in a counter example.

Comment: Thanks! Do you by any chance know a simpler counter example without that 'strange' product? Otherwise I will try my best to understand it, thanks

Comment: The notation may be strange but the operator itself is very simple: $B_n$ takes the first component to the $n$-th component, multiplies with $1/n$ and sets all other components to $0$. $A_n$ takes the $n$th component to the first component, multiplies with $2^n$ and sets all other components to $0$.

Comment: I added some questions above, I hope you can answer them. Thanks a lot!

Comment: and in $e_k\otimes e_j^*( e_n) = \delta_{jn} e_n$, don't we have a $k$ somewhere on the right hand side too?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo, $e_k\otimes e_j^*(e_n) = e_k \delta_{jn}$. Basically $A_n(e_k) = 2^n e_1 \delta_{kn}$ and $B_n( e_k) = \frac1n e_n \delta_{k1}$, so $A_nB_n(e_k) = 2^n/n e_1 \delta_{k1}$